# Is there any other usage or difference between Expect vs done.fail?

Tags: jasmine

[image]
Please find the pros and cons of expect and done.fail which i found which identified, Is there any other  usage or difference between Expect vs done.fail?

Expect- Soft assertion,

done.fail hard assertion

Comment: This is not a question as far as I can tell. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: I wanted to understand the other difference between expect vs done.fail

Comment: Please update your question to make that clear. Otherwise, there's no way of knowing what you're asking.